# What is this style of import, that names no symbols and lacks the `from` keyword?

Tags: javascript

```js
// file api_setup.js
import { ApiProxy } from "vendor-lib"

ApiProxy.configure({ /* ... */ })

export { ApiProxy }
```

```js
// file service.js
import "./api_setup" // ?

/* ... */
```

I believe this is old code, so I looked at [the NodeJS doc on `import` from a few years ago](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers), and it doesn't cover anything like `import "./api_setup"`.

What is this style of import called? What does it do?

Comment: It just loads and executes the file. Useful if you only need side effects.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_ - An opinion is not a specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [MDN documentation for `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only):

> ### Import a module for its side effects only
>
> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing
> anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually
> import any values.
>
> ```
> import '/modules/my-module.js';
> ```